# Subcaption package creates incorrect cross-references to sub-figures

Tags: hyperref, numbering, subfloats, subcaption

I'm trying to place a figure that already has subcaptions. I wrote:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
A reference to \autoref{fig1c}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{Image description:
\textbf{(a)}~number 1, 
\textbf{(b)}~number 2,
\textbf{(c)}~number 3 and
\textbf{(d)}~number 4
\label{fig1}}
\phantomsubcaption\label{fig1a}
\phantomsubcaption\label{fig1b}
\phantomsubcaption\label{fig1c}
\phantomsubcaption\label{fig1d}
\end{figure}

a reference to \autoref{fig1d}

\end{document}
```

But when I cross-reference the figures, their number is incorrect.

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Just place the `\phantomsubcaption` and associated `\label` instructions *before* the main `\caption` directive (and its associated `\label` instruction).

Comment: @Mico I did it: `\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}
\phantomsubcaption\label{fig1a}
\phantomsubcaption\label{fig1b}
\phantomsubcaption\label{fig1c}
\phantomsubcaption\label{fig1d}
\caption{Image description:
\textbf{(a)}~number 1, 
\textbf{(b)}~number 2,
\textbf{(c)}~number 3 and
\textbf{(d)}~number 4
\label{fig1}}
\end{figure}` but the Figure label is (e)

Comment: Please note that `\phantomsubcaption` should be used in its own box or group only, as the warnings (and the manual) suggest!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - Your comment preceded my answer by a few seconds... :-)

Comment: @DanielValencia - Please see the answer I posted a few minutes ago.

Comment: @Mico: As was your first comment before I could answer, so I refrained;-)

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

You need to make two changes:

- Place the `\phantomsubcaption` and associated `\label` instructions *before* the main `\caption` directive and its associated `\label` instruction.
- The `\phantomsubcaption` directives *must* be placed in a TeX group by themselves. (See p. 10 of the user guide of the `subcaption` package.)

A full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref} % <-- load this package **last**

\begin{document}
A cross-reference to \autoref{fig1c}.

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}
\begingroup % encase the \phantomsubcaption directives in a TeX group
\phantomsubcaption\label{fig1a}
\phantomsubcaption\label{fig1b}
\phantomsubcaption\label{fig1c}
\phantomsubcaption\label{fig1d}
\endgroup
\caption{%
\textbf{(a)}~number 1, 
\textbf{(b)}~number 2,
\textbf{(c)}~number 3, and
\textbf{(d)}~number 4}
\label{fig1}
\end{figure}

A cross-reference to \autoref{fig1d}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works perfectly in the example, but when I try this in the document that I'm writing It doesn't work. I'm working on a paper using mdpi class. Any help?

Comment: @DanielValencia - I'm afraid I've never heard of the `mdpi` document class, and it doesn't appear to be on TeXLive or on the CTAN. Is it available online somewhere? If so, you may to provide a link.

Comment: sure http://www.mdpi.com/authors/latex

Comment: The `mdpi` document class appears to mess up all kinds of things related to cross-referencing -- and not just with respect to subfigures and subtables. If you have `mdpi`-specific concerns, you should post a new query -- with, as always, an MWE -- in which you state clearly which problems your're encountering. (Unfortunately, statements such as "it doesn't work" simply are not specific enough to be actionable.) Providing a link to the source of the `mdpi`-related files would also be a good idea.